# Is there a way to reuse pthreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have a function that is called millions of times, and the work done by this function is multithreaded. Here is the function:

```
void functionCalledSoManyTimes()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
  {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, thread_work_function, (void *)&thread_data[i]);
  }
  // wait
}
```

I'm creating the threads each time the function is called, and I give each thread its data struct (that's been set once at the beginning of the algorithm) to use in the `thread_work_function`. The `thread_work_function`simply processes a series of arrays, and the `thread_data` struct contains pointers to those arrays and the indices that each thread is responsible for.

Although multithreading the algorithm in this way did improve the performance by more than 20%, my profiling shows that the repetitive calls to pthread_create are causing a significant overhead.

My question is: Is there a way to achieve my goal without calling `pthread_create` each time the function is called?

**Problem Solved.**

Thank you guys, I really appreciate your help! I've written a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12282393/408286) using your tips.

Comment: You need to look at a *thread pool* concept. Here you have a pool of threads, which wait for work. You schedule this work, say in a queue - which the threads a blocked on, and one thread will pick up the work and execute it. This is a fairly common concept, and if you have the possibility, pull in this functionality from something like the APR (Apache Portable Runtime.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start a fixed set of threads and use an inter-thread communication system (ring buffer, for instance) to pass the data to process.

Answer (score 2):

Solving the problem gracefully is not so easy. You can use static storage for a thread pool, but then what happens if `functionCalledSoManyTimes` itself can be called from multiple threads? It's not a good design.

What I would do to handle this sort of situation is create a thread-local storage key with `pthread_key_create` on the first call (using `pthread_once`), and store your thread-pool there with `pthread_setspecific` the first time `functionCalledSoManyTimes` gets called in a given thread. You can provide a destructor function to `pthread_key_create` which will get called when the the thread exists, and this function can then be responsible for signaling the worker threads in the thread pool to terminate themselves (via `pthread_cancel` or some other mechanism).

Comment: Sometimes you can boot the problem upstairs - require the caller of `functionCalledSoManyTimes` to pass in a thread pool that's created/destroyed by functions you provide for them. This is an easy change if the caller's code looks like `for (int i = 0; i < SOMANY; ++i) functionCalledSoManyTimes();`, not easy if the function is called from many unrelated sites, and easy but useless if you want to hide the fact that it's multi-threaded from the caller.

Comment: That's also a nice solution, but I suspect it's often not applicable, especially if you want to keep the implementation of `functionCalledSoManyTimes` opaque/encapsulated.

Comment: Agreed. I mention it because I'd want to rule it out before introducing hidden shared state, whether that's static or thread-local. If I fail to rule it out, that's a bonus. Another possibility would be to tell the caller that what they're creating and passing in is a `ManyTimesFunctionOptimizer`. That secretly contains a thread pool, and your function implementation is encapsulated other than the fact that it can optionally re-use this object to get a speed boost. Whether that object contains a thread pool or a memoization cache (or both) is opaque to the caller.